How to make tomcat (spring boot embeded tomcat 10.x) to close the connection if the server(backend code) is taking too long?
I am using spring boot 3.x and hence I am using the embeded tomcat (10.x)

Sometimes the my app's rest service call's server processing could take too long ( over one minute).
But we don't want the user to wait for this long but want to timeout in 20 seconds, so they can try again. For the application I am dealing with, this kind of approach is ok though in general it may not be best.
So, when user makes a rest request and the server exceeds 20s processing, i want the socket/connection to be closed with 400 or 500 response. Is this possible to configure this through spring-tomcat config props in application.yml.
I have gone through How to Configure Spring Boot Tomcat. This speaks about server.connection-timeout=5s, but this is different from what I am looking for.

Tomcat provides the Stuck Thread Detection Valve which detects requests taking too much time to process, and optionally interrupts the thread processing such a request.
The following code configures the time thresholds  in this valve to satisfy the requirement:

backgroundProcessorDelay < threshold < interruptThreadThreshold

@Bean
WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> stuckThreadDetectionCustomizer(
    @Value("${tomcat.stuck-thread-detection.threshold:20s}") Duration threshold,
    ServerProperties serverProperties
) {
  int thresholdSeconds = (int) Math.max(
      threshold.toSeconds(),
      serverProperties.getTomcat().getBackgroundProcessorDelay().toSeconds() + 1);
  int interruptThreadThresholdSeconds = thresholdSeconds + 1;
  return factory -> {
      var stuckThreadDetectionValve = new StuckThreadDetectionValve();
      stuckThreadDetectionValve.setThreshold(thresholdSeconds);
      stuckThreadDetectionValve.setInterruptThreadThreshold(interruptThreadThresholdSeconds);
      factory.addContextValves(stuckThreadDetectionValve);
  };
}


in the official documentation https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/config/valve.html#Stuck_Thread_Detection_Valve it is possible to set the threshold timeout value with attribute threshold. So no need for Java code at all. Only configure to context.xml or server.xml

@DudiBoy - gr8 ref. But in spring boot project there is no context.xml or server.xml, so how can i configure it with out code. Could you please elaborate.

@samshers. To configure additional valves in the context.xml file for a Java Spring Boot application using Tomcat 10 without Java code, you'll need to create or modify the context.xml file directly. Here's how to do it:
First, create a file named context.xml if it doesn't already exist. For a Spring Boot application, you should place this file in the following directory:
src/main/resources/META-INF/context.xml
Open the context.xml file and add your valve configurations within the  element.

@DudiBoy - i have added <Context>     <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.StuckThreadDetectionValve"            threshold="4"            interruptThreadThreshold="4" /> </Context>  in META-INF/context.xml  but i don't see the timeout happening.

@DudiBoy - the bean approach is working as expected, but i will prefer the context.xml approach if it can be made to work.
